# Python. Получить дату и время файла (timestamp) с HTTP сервера

Tags: python, python-3.x, timestamp

Мне нужно с помощью программы на языке Python скачать файл с HTTP сервера с сохранением оригинальной даты (timestamp) создания файла.

Соответственно два вопроса:

1. Как получить дату файла с HTTP сервера с помощью Python 3.7?
2. Как установить эту дату для скачанного файла?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот пример кода

```
import urllib.request
import os
import time
import datetime


link = 'http://www.lib.ru/INPROZ/STINE/alice_001.jpg'
destination = link.rsplit('/',1)[1]

#читаем атрибуты файла
site = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
meta = site.info()

#скачиваем файл
urllib.request.urlretrieve(link, destination)

#читаем дату последнего изменения из атрибутов
date_time_str = meta['Last-Modified']

#конвертируем ее объект datetime
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT')
modTime = time.mktime(date.timetuple())

#изменяем дату создания файла
os.utime(destination, (modTime, modTime))
```

Comment: Здравствуйте becouse. Я тут недавно и пока не понял наказуемо ли оставлять неинформативные комментарии, но всё-таки рискну. Вы не только помогли мне решить задачу, но ещё из Вашего ответа я почерпнул информацию которая поможет мне делать некоторые операции проще, чем я делал ранее. Большое Вам спасибо!